# error: cannot find symbol class 'or' in ParseQuery.or();

Tags: android, parse-server

I'm trying to add a query by using the 'or' method.

`ParseQuery<ParseObject> myquery = new ParseQuery.or(allqueries);`
but when I write this line .or I turns into red and show "cannot find symbol or".
Although other parse functions working fine.
`

```
dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
        implementation "com.github.parse-community.Parse-SDK-Android:parse:1.22.1"
        implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.4.2'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    }`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9Kpr.jpg)

Comment: try `ParseQuery myquery = ParseQuery.or(allqueries);` may its static method

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing a static method so remove the `new` keyword

Replace Line with

`ParseQuery myquery = ParseQuery.or(allqueries);`